# How to check graphical mode in Python PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have simple (puzzles) game written in Python with PyGame.

How can I check to see if Python is in graphical or console mode? Ex. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> in Ubuntu. In cli mode, my puzzles crash. If I try to display images and stuff in this mode, it's pretty awful. This code below is not working:

```
try
    pygame.init()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((PICTURE_WIDTH,PICTURE_HEIGHT))       
    pygame.display.set_caption('ImagePuzzles')
    self.screen.fill((255,255,255))
    self.gameIsStarted = False
except:
    print "Game only for graphics mode."
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout ENVIRONMENT variables

```
import os
os.environ['TERM'] #"linux" in console mode, "xterm" on graphic terminal
```

'DISPLAY' is set in graphic mode, 'DESKTOP_SESSION' set if user logged in Desktop(gnome,kde etc.).

Put it at begining

```
import os,sys
try:
    assert 'DISPLAY' in os.environ
except AssertionError:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux and other Unixes that uses the X server for graphical environment (essentially all of them), graphical programs run in the X display pointed by the DISPLAY environment variable. It is usually considered a user error to start a graphical program in a text terminal without setting the DISPLAY environment variable to a valid X display name. This variable is set by default when you start a program from inside graphical environment and you can check for this variable.